# xml parsing using DOM in android

Tags: android

Iam working on Rss feeds.Iam using DOM parser

```
The actual link is:

http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNEd3ZGNLp5P-6bn44JmKbPfQimTyQ&url=http://www.foxnews.com/world/2012/09/21/libyans-storm-ansar-al-sharia-compound-in-backlash-attack-on-us-consulate/

After executing the function    xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
URL=https://news.google.com/news/feeds?ned=us&topic=w&output=rss



In xml Iam getting the link as:

http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNHrclA7rxiQuEvAA_o9ZDRlZQFLkg&amp;url=http://www.usatoday.com/news/world/story/2012/09/21/libyans-storm-militia-in-backlash-of-attack-on-us/57821580/1
```

when I pasted this url in browser it is showing "This is an invalid url".

```
How to get the a valid url? Could anyone please help me.
```

Below function is to get xml from url:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try with piece of code and change as per your variables....

```
try {
    // Create a URL for the desired page
        String stringURL = "http://link;
        URL url = new URL(stringURL);
        // Read all the text returned by the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                url.openStream()));
        while ((xml = in.readLine()) != null) {
            stringXml += xml;

        }
        in.close();

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(stringXml)));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("nodename");
            Node node = nodeLst.item(0);
            String demo1 = node.getTextContent();

            nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("nodename");
            node = nodeLst.item(0);
            String demo2= node.getTextContent();
            nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("nodename");
            node = nodeLst.item(0);
            String demo3= node.getTextContent();
            nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("nodename");
            node = nodeLst.item(0);
            String demo4= node.getTextContent();
            nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("nodename");
            node = nodeLst.item(0);
            String demo5= node.getTextContent();
            nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("nodename");
            node = nodeLst.item(0);
            String demo6= node.getTextContent();


            nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("nodename");
            node = nodeLst.item(0);

            nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("nodename");
            node = nodeLst.item(0);
            password="+username.getText();
            }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i m using parsing using dom ...it is to be great to understand that is in best manner in single activity of program  very very shortcut to be use .you have not seen i think before .

public class MainActivity  extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Create a new layout to display the view */
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(1);

    /** Create a new textview array to display the results */
    TextView name[];
    TextView website[];
    TextView category[];

    try {

        URL url = new URL(
                "http://xyz.com/aa.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
        name = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        website = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        category = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            name[i] = new TextView(this);
            website[i] = new TextView(this);
            category[i] = new TextView(this);

            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
            NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("name");
            Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
            nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
            name[i].setText("Name = "
                    + ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("website");
            Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
            websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
            website[i].setText("Website = "
                    + ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            category[i].setText("Website Category = "
                    + websiteElement.getAttribute("category"));

            layout.addView(name[i]);
            layout.addView(website[i]);
            layout.addView(category[i]);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }

    /** Set the layout view to display */
    setContentView(layout);

}
```

}
....................
in manyfeast u can add

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>